# What data of images are given to kmeans clustering in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, k-means, pca

Iam having 100 images in my database.Iam using those 100 images as both training set and also test images.I have to make 5 clusters.Iam using eigen faces(PCA) for feature extraction.What data should be given for kmeans command in matlab?

**Syntax for kmeans command:**

**[IDX,C] = kmeans(X,k)**

1.What is the X value?

2.Whether we have to give euclidian distance as input?

3.Whether we have to give weight vector of input images?

Please explain me in detail.

Source code i tried

```
X = []
    srcFiles = dir('C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\tomorow\*.jpg');  % the folder in which ur images exists
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    filename = strcat('C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\tomorow\',srcFiles(b).name);
    Imgdata = imread(filename);
    X(:,  i) = princomp(Imgdata); 
end
[idx, c] = kmeans(X, 5)
```

Error iam getting:

**Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in pca (line 4)
    filename =strcat('C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\tomorow\',srcFiles(b).name);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PCA function you are using (I don't know what it is exactly), produces a vector of n numbers. This vectors describes the picture, and is what needs to be given to the k-means algorithm.

First of all, run the PCA for all 100 images, producing a nX100 matrix.

```
X = []
for i = 1 : 100
    X(:,  i) = PCA(picture...) 
end
```

If pca return a line instead of column, you need

```
X(:, i) = PCA(picture)'
```

The k-means functions takes this parameter, as well as the number  k of clusters. So

```
[idx, c] = kmeans(X, 5);
```

The distance used for clustering is euclidean by default. If you want some different distance metric, you can supply it as a parameter. See the table [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) for the available distance metrics.

Finally, the standard k-means algorithm is not weighted, so you can't supply weights to the vectors.

Comment: iam getting this error:X=[] Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: X = []
    srcFiles = dir('C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\tomorow\*.jpg');  
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    filename = strcat('C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\tomorow\',srcFiles(b).name);
    Imgdata = imread(filename);
    X(:,  i) = PCA(Imgdata); 
end
[idx, c] = kmeans(X, 5)

Comment: please check my question i have added code that i have tried.Please help me out.Iam getting error.

Comment: My mistake. X(:,i) = ... assigns a column to a column of a matrix that already has the desired size. So , before the "for" loop, it should be X = zeros(100, N), where N is the length of the vector returned by PCA. About the filename error, I can't know, it's something in your local path. Check that the image is really loaded (imshow(imgData)) before passing it to pca. If not, try putting your images in the same folder as the code. Hard coded paths are problematic in most languages.

Comment: Again i got this error message:Attempt to execute SCRIPT pca as a function

Comment: i updated my question with one more code.please check it. question

Comment: pca(x) is the name of the function, replace it with your correct function name (seems to be princomp in your code). about the path error i can't know, print the filenames to see that they are correct. also (in general) place the files in a folder inside your source folder, avoid paths with "c:\..." because they differ between systems and languages